# Death Knight Hero after Jaraxxus/Amara?

Tags: hearthstone

Jaraxxus and Amara, Warden of Hope are both cards that change your hero's maximum life total. If you play one of the new Death Knight Heroes after having played Jaraxxus or Amara, what happens to your life total? Would your max health be returned to 30 or would you keep the 15/40 max life given by Jaraxxus/Amara?

Comment: Jaraxxus and Amara work a little differently though. Jaraxxus sets your health to 15. Amara sets your maximum health to 40 and then HEALS you based on the difference of your current and health and 40. That is a small but very important difference between the two cards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the changes to your maximum health stay. To demonstrate:

Jaraxxus:
[image]
After hero power still at 15:
[image]
Amara:
[image]
Healing back up to 40:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

DK heroes don't change your health value like Jaraxxus and Amara. They do, however, give you a bit of armor. If you're Jaraxxus at 13 HP and you play a DK card, you'll simply to go 13 HP and 4-6 armor (depending on the DK).